# Bitmap heap spray technique

Tags: exploit, heapspray

I was recently reading up a PDF (https://www.owasp.org/images/0/01/OWASL_IL_2010_Jan_-_Moshe_Ben_Abu_-_Advanced_Heapspray.pdf) heap spray techniques when they mentioned heap spray with bitmaps. Now they didn't exactly explain how one could do, or accomplish this technique. When I tried looking up techniques on bitmap heap spraying it just came up with normal heap spray. So what I am asking is for some article ,webpage, or PDF that explains, and shows a brief piece of code how to accomplish a bitmap heap spray. (Also if someone could also give a short explanation on how heap spray with bitmap works that would help me out a lot too. Thanks!)

Comment: can you provide the name of this PDF you were reading and/or a link to it

Comment: I did. Maby the site blocked the url?

Comment: their I have included the link ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea is to embed shellcode in a bitmap which a browser loads into the heap.

The original presentation discussing this technique is [Punk Ode: Hiding Shellcode in Plain Sight](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-06/BH-US-06-Sutton.pdf).

[image: slide 23]

Also discussed in this paper is [using code embedded in a gif to create an exploitable heap overflow](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157646) in NetScape 6.x, x86 Linux RedHat 7.0, 15 years ago (slide 9).

As for the technique discussed on slide 13 of [Advanced Heap Spraying Techniques](https://www.owasp.org/images/0/01/OWASL_IL_2010_Jan_-_Moshe_Ben_Abu_-_Advanced_Heapspray.pdf), the code used to demonstrate it can be found  in the section titled "**Alternative ways to spray the browser heap**" of  [corelan's **Heap Spraying Demystified** tutorial](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/12/31/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-11-heap-spraying-demystified/):

```
# written by Moshe Ben Abu (Trancer) of www.rec-sec.com
# published on www.corelan.be with permission

bmp_width           = ARGV[0].to_i
bmp_height          = ARGV[1].to_i
bmp_files_togen     = ARGV[2].to_i

if (ARGV[0] == nil)
    bmp_width       = 1024
end

if (ARGV[1] == nil)
    bmp_height      = 768
end

if (ARGV[2] == nil)
    bmp_files_togen = 128
end

# size of bitmap file calculation
bmp_header_size     = 54
bmp_raw_offset      = 40
bits_per_pixel      = 24
bmp_row_size        = 4 * ((bits_per_pixel.to_f * bmp_width.to_f) / 32)
bmp_file_size       = 54 + (4 * ( bits_per_pixel ** 2 ) ) + ( bmp_row_size * bmp_height )

bmp_file            = "\x00" * bmp_file_size
bmp_header          = "\x00" * bmp_header_size
bmp_raw_size        = bmp_file_size - bmp_header_size

# generate bitmap file header
bmp_header[0,2]     = "\x42\x4D"                    # "BM"
bmp_header[2,4]     = [bmp_file_size].pack('V')     # size of bitmap file
bmp_header[10,4]    = [bmp_header_size].pack('V')   # size of bitmap header (54 bytes)
bmp_header[14,4]    = [bmp_raw_offset].pack('V')    # number of bytes in the bitmap header from here
bmp_header[18,4]    = [bmp_width].pack('V')         # width of the bitmap (pixels)
bmp_header[22,4]    = [bmp_height].pack('V')        # height of the bitmap (pixels)
bmp_header[26,2]    = "\x01\x00"                    # number of color planes (1 plane)
bmp_header[28,2]    = "\x18\x00"                    # number of bits (24 bits)
bmp_header[34,4]    = [bmp_raw_size].pack('V')      # size of raw bitmap data

bmp_file[0,bmp_header.length] = bmp_header

bmp_file[bmp_header.length,bmp_raw_size] = "\x0C" * bmp_raw_size

for i in 1..bmp_files_togen do
    bmp = File.new(i.to_s+".bmp","wb")
    bmp.write(bmp_file)
    bmp.close
end
```

> This standalone ruby script will create a basic bmp image that contains 0x0c all over the place. Run the script, feeding it the desired width and height of the bmp file, and the number of files to create :

```
root@bt:/spray# ruby bmpheapspray_standalone.rb 1024 768 1
root@bt:/spray# ls -al
total 2320
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 2011-12-31 08:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4096 2011-12-31 08:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2361654 2011-12-31 08:52 1.bmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1587 2011-12-31 08:51 bmpheapspray_standalone.rb
root@bt:/spray#
```

Additional information on this subject from Phrack article [Self-patching Microsoft XML with misalignments and factorials](http://phrack.org/issues/69/10.html):

> --[ 3.4 - Filling the memory 1: images
>
> Because the memory region that must be controlled is rather big, my
>   initial idea was to utilize some pre-calculated big objects for filling
>   it, such as images. The core of the idea is that, every piece of data
>   that can be consumed and processed by the target application (e.g. output
>   or rendered) has its place and a representation in the target process
>   memory. Thinking like that we don't get caught in stereotypical terms of
>   'heap spraying' and the specific techniques associated with it, many of
>   which are already mitigated in browsers.
>
> The idea of using graphical images in vulnerability development is not
>   new. It was first introduced in 2006 by Sutton et al.[3], whose research
>   focused mainly on the aesthetics of shellcode steganography in images
>   rather than solving of any problems of heap spraying (as there were none
>   at that time). Later, a few researchers revisited the same idea in the
>   context of heap spraying, but it has never found a real application,
>   mainly because bitmaps (as the only format capable of incorporating a
>   byte pattern 'as is') are huge and can only be shrinked with the help of
>   server-side measures, while using other image formats for memory control
>   purposes is burdened with calculation problems of recompression.
>
> Apart from the server-side GZIP compression, another solution that's never
>   publicly noted is PNG. The PNG compression is very simple and does not
>   affect the bitmap structure at large. As a result, a 2Mb BMP image
>   containing a simple 1-byte pattern can be converted into a ~500 bytes PNG
>   image, that will be decompressed back into the original bitmap in the
>   rendering process memory.
>
> There are two problems however:
>
> 1. The more variable is the source bitmap pattern, the bigger is the
>      resulting PNG image; a natural limitation of any compression.
> 2. The decompressed PNG has extra bytes in the bitmap data, injected after
>      every 3 bytes of the original bitmap. It's probably a transparency channel
>      or some other data specific to the PNG format.
>
> The good news:
>
> 1. At the point when the PNG image is loaded and decompressed by the
>      browser but is not yet displayed on the web page, the bitmap data in the
>      process memory fully corresponds to the source BMP.
> 2. A large image is mapped into a comparably large and continuous chunk of
>      memory, located at a somewhat predictable memory offset.
>
> The PNG spraying technique proved to be not suitable for this particular
>   case because a highly variable memory padding pattern would be required,
>   and so the images would have to be too big anyway. However it still looks
>   like an interesting technique for rapid filling of huge memory areas with
>   a simple byte pattern.